# Minimizing trigonometric function over a limited domain.

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

It's been a while since I have done any sort of optimization problems.  Consider the function:

$$f(x)=-a_1\sin(x)-a_3\sin(3x).$$

We want to find the minimum $c$ and $a_3$ at that minimum value, such that
$$|-a_1\sin(x)-a_3\sin(3x)|\leq c$$
Subject to the domain constraint of $x \in [0,\alpha]$ and the constraint that $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}\cos^{-1}(a_1)$ and $0<\alpha< \pi/3$

I'm really not sure where to even start on this question, hopefully somebody finds this as interesting as I do!

Comment: You want to minimize $c$? What are the decision variables? $a_1,a_3,c$, and $\alpha$?

Comment: HI David,

$\alpha$ is fixed to $a_1$ and can't be any smaller than $4/\pi \cos(\alpha)$ and no larger than 1.  So, I need to find what the minimum value of $c$ is, as well as what the corresponding $a_3$ would be, as it should change depending on $\alpha$...

Comment: I'm sorry--I'm sort of confused by the notation. So you want to solve this problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min\ & c\\
\text{s.t.}\ & |a_1\sin(x)+a_2\sin(3x)|\leq{c}\ \forall\ x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\cos^{-1}(a_1)]\\
& 0<\cos^{-1}(a_1)<4/3\\
&a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{R}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
Is that right?

Comment: That looks right. :)

Comment: It would helpful to edit your post to reflect this